# What causes the error message "This browser or app may not be secure" and how can it be resolved?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have encountered the following warning message: "This browser or app may not be secure" while accessing a website or using an application. The message appears to be a security-related alert, but I'm not sure what steps I should take to address it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

with open('credentials.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        username = row[0]
        password = row[1]
        
        
        user_agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

        options = Options()
        options.accept_insecure_certs = True
        options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
        options.add_argument("--user-agent=%s" % user_agent)
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
        options.add_argument("--disable-impl-side-painting")
        options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
        options.add_argument("--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        options.accept_insecure_certs = True
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        # executable_path = r'C:\Users\mdmsd2\Desktop\MEGAsync\Selenium_youtube\chromedriver.exe'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier')

        email_input = driver.find_element(By.ID,"identifierId")
        email_input.send_keys(username)
        next_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierNext')
        next_button.click()
        
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        password_input.send_keys(password)
        submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span')
        submit_button.click()

        driver.implicitly_wait(10) # wait for page to load
        if driver.current_url == 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox':
            print(f'Logged in successfully as {username}')
            with open('successful_logins.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([username])
        else:
            print(f'Failed to login as {username}')

        driver.maximize_window()
```

Could someone please explain the possible causes behind this warning and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Additionally, are there any specific actions I need to take to ensure the safety of my browsing or app usage? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying this code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

with open('credentials.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        username = row[0]
        password = row[1]
        
        
        user_agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

        options = Options()
        options.accept_insecure_certs = True
        options.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = True
        options.add_argument("--user-agent=%s" % user_agent)
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
        options.add_argument("--disable-impl-side-painting")
        options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
        options.add_argument("--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        options.accept_insecure_certs = True
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        # executable_path = r'C:\Users\mdmsd2\Desktop\MEGAsync\Selenium_youtube\chromedriver.exe'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier')

        email_input = driver.find_element(By.ID,"identifierId")
        email_input.send_keys(username)
        next_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierNext')
        next_button.click()
        
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        password_input.send_keys(password)
        submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span')
        submit_button.click()

        driver.implicitly_wait(10) # wait for page to load
        if driver.current_url == 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox':
            print(f'Logged in successfully as {username}')
            with open('successful_logins.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([username])
        else:
            print(f'Failed to login as {username}')

        driver.maximize_window()
```

and getting "This browser or app may not be secure" warning message and selenium automated process did not complited.

Comment: You're getting detected. Using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver might solve your issue.

Comment: I am already tried that way.

Comment: then please update your code

Comment: please check this screenshot
[link](https://imgur.com/a/HQRnek8)